# Which decision tree algorithm does H2O use?

Tags: decision-trees, h2o

Does H2O's plain random forest use CART, C4.5, 5.0, or something else? I cannot find this information. sklearn's docs say they use a modified version of CART, and I assume H2O also uses something like CART.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard H20 Driverless AI uses an ensemble of xgboost and lightgbm models. In some situations it uses tensorflow neural nets as well.

Comment: I meant their vanilla random forests.